# Grouped Array data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to get data from the following data structure. I managed to group a flat array into the following array, but am finding it difficult to find the proper resources to explain how to get the data out. I'm looking to get the count of the items in each group. Then i'd like to print the ids from the inner array...

```
array (
  'grinds' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 16562,
      'slug' => 'grinds',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 16561,
      'slug' => 'grinds',
    ),
  ),
  'online-grinds' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 16566,
      'slug' => 'online-grinds',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Where is this array coming from?  Can you sum at the source (presumably at the db level?)

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far please. I assume you must at least of tried a foreach loop or 2

Comment: Thanks for the reply folks. I had tried a foreach loop but hadn't been able to successfully implement the inner foreach loop as demonstrated by EvE in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$my_array1 = array(
    'grinds' =>
        array(
            0 =>
                array(
                    'id' => 16562,
                    'slug' => 'grinds',
                ),
            1 =>
                array(
                    'id' => 16561,
                    'slug' => 'grinds',
                ),
        ),
    'online-grinds' =>
        array(
            0 =>
                array(
                    'id' => 16566,
                    'slug' => 'online-grinds',
                ),
        ),
);
```

get counts:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($my_array1 as $key => $val) {
    $counts[$key] = count($val);
}
var_dump($counts);
```

yields:

```
array(2) {
    ["grinds"]=>
    int(2)
    ["online-grinds"]=>
    int(1)
}
```

get inner ids:

```
$innerids = array();
foreach ($my_array1 as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2) {
        $innerids[] = $val2['id'];
    }
}
var_dump($innerids);
```

yields:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(16562)
    [1]=>
    int(16561)
    [2]=>
    int(16566)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and then for every item use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and specifing the field name and then use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the unique values.

Then combine those in an array and use the existing key again as the key for then new array.

```
$arrays = array_map(function($x) {
    return [
        array_count_values(array_column($x, 'id')),
        array_count_values(array_column($x, 'slug'))
        ];
}, $arrays);

print_r($arrays);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [grinds] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [16562] => 1
                    [16561] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [grinds] => 2
                )

        )

    [online-grinds] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [16566] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [online-grinds] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gK5kE)